# Error in upload dotnet project framework heroku hosting

Tags: asp.net, .net, heroku, frameworks

I can not upload the web application on Heroku because of an error with the framework.

When i use stack cedar-14 me give error 
[image]

When i user stack heroku-18 -

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: And please make sure to include all relevant log output in your question. Too much is better than not enough.